# how to write a cleaner comparison

Tags: algorithm

Hi I'm not familiar with algorithm, so I'm asking help for this simple comparison. So I have two unsigned int arrays with size N. and I need to compare which one is bigger. How I compare is I start from the left element, and if A[i] is bigger than B[i], then A array > B array.if they are equal, I compare A[i+1] and B[i+1]. A brut force way to do so is:

```
BOOL checkArray(int[] A, int[] B) {
    for(i=0; i< N; i ++){ 
       if (A[i] > B[i]) {
           return TRUE;
       }else if (A[i] == B[i]) {
           continue;
       } else {  \\ A[i] < B[i]
           return FALSE;
       }
    }
}
```

Please advise if there's a better way to achieve this. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I think it's OK. But needs a `return (EQUAL)` at the end of the for loop (when all A[i] are equal to B[i]).

Comment: based on your desired result there is no more efficient way to do this. You will have to compare index by index, which will make the algorithm O(n)

Comment: @ypercube I'm sure you mean to return FALSE and not EQUAL :)  and of course you what to make sure that the variable i has been declared an int somewhere...

Comment: @Jimmy: Well, either `TRUE` or `FALSE` or change the return type of the function to having 3 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the standard library's implementation of strcmp.

```
bool checkArray (int [] a, int [] b)
{
  int
     i = 0;

  while (i < N && a [i] == b [i])
  {
    ++i;
  }

  return i < N && a [i] > b [i]; // return false if arrays equal
  //return i >= N || a [i] > b [i]; // return true if arrays equal
}
```

Your example code, however, has a route out of the function that is undefined - that is, is all elements of A are equal to all elements of B.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly normal and valid way:) Nothing better than that.

Just be sure to return properly if all elements are equal.

Comment: Well, you *could* turn the arrays into strings and use string comparison, because most character encodings conveniently produce the same comparison values as numbers do... (not any faster, but maybe prettier code)

Answer (score 0):

basically its ok, but to follow the .NET comparison schema you should return an integer.
Like that you can use it directly for sorting too if you ever need that

i would implement it like that:

```
public class StringArrayComparer : IComparer<String[]>
{
    #region IComparer<string[]> Members

    public int Compare(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("The two arrays dont have same size");

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            int strComp = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
            if (strComp != 0)
                return strComp;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}
```